# Square Retrofit Client: How to enable/disable followRedirects? How to intercept redirect URL?

Tags: java, android, networking, retrofit

I'm using Square's Retrofit Client to make simple requests from an Android App. Like so:

```
  RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setServer(Configurations.getInstance().plistMap.get("PTBaseURL"))
            .setRequestHeaders(new RequestHeaders() {
                @Override
                public List<Header> get() {
                    List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
                        Header authHeader = new Header("Authorization", authType + " " + UserManager.getInstance().currentUser.token);
                        headers.add(authHeader);
                    }
                    return headers;
                }
            })
            .build();

    this.service = restAdapter.create(ClientInterface.class);
```

One endpoint redirects to a different URL (s3). For an reason not important to this question the redirect request is failing and thus my `callback.failure(error)` method is being called. I need to be able to access and modify the redirect URL or request at some point, preferable in `callback.failure()`. How can I do this?

Alternatively, is there a way to set something like `followRedirects = false` (and intercept the redirect in this way)?

Answer (score 10):

With `OkHttp`:

```
 public static void setFollowRedirects (boolean auto)
 public OkHttpClient setFollowProtocolRedirects(boolean followProtocolRedirects)
```

With `HttpURLConnection`:

```
public static void setFollowRedirects (boolean auto)
public void setInstanceFollowRedirects (boolean followRedirects)
```

See discussion [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/305).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for POST requests: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3111