# Android Retrofit with redirection

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-sheets, retrofit, okhttp

I am developing simple Android app where I am using google spreadsheet as a data source. For communication I am using google app script which implements doPost method because my app is sending some data to sheet and also wants some data as a response. The problem is instead of json response I always get html response about redirection in the errorBody().

I have also set OkHttpClient with redirections enabled to my retrofit service, but result is still the same.

I am working with Insomnia rest client for debugging and when I set redirections on there, everything works there fine.

If somebody had the same problem and solved it, please help.

**Edit:**

Here is my code:

```
public class Connector {

private static final String BASE_URL = "https://script.googleusercontent.com/";
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
private static CallTaxiService service;
private static final String TAG = "Connector";

private static CallTaxiService getService()
{
    if (service == null)
    {
        synchronized(LOCK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "creating instance");
            service = buildService();
        }
    }
    return service;
}

private static CallTaxiService buildService()
{
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().followRedirects(true)
                    .followSslRedirects(true).build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    return retrofit.create(CallTaxiService.class);
}




public static void syncData(List<TaxiServiceAppData> data, Callback<Response> callback)
{
    Call<Response> call = getService().sendData(data);
    Log.d(TAG, "syncing data");
    call.enqueue(callback);
}

private interface CallTaxiService {
    @Headers({"Content-type: application/json"})
    @POST("endpoint_url")
    Call<Response> sendData(@Body List<TaxiServiceAppData> data);
}
```

}

And here is how I am calling it:

```
            Connector.syncData(taxiServiceAppData, new retrofit2.Callback<com.adrisoft.calltaxi.model.Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<com.adrisoft.calltaxi.model.Response> call, Response<com.adrisoft.calltaxi.model.Response> response) {
                com.adrisoft.calltaxi.model.Response data = response.body();
                if (data != null) {
                    newCities = data.getCities();
                    newTaxis = data.getTaxis();
                    updateDb();
                    prefs.saveSyncTime();
                    isSyncRunning = false;
                    callback.onSuccess();
                } else {
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Sync failed ... no data available. Error: " + response.errorBody().string());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                    }

                    callback.onFailure();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<com.adrisoft.calltaxi.model.Response> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Sync request failed.");
                isSyncRunning = false;
                callback.onFailure();
            }
        });
```

And exactly in the log "Sync failed ... no data available ..." I am getting this from errorBody():

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Temporary Redirect</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Temporary Redirect</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://script.google.com/endpoint_url">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: could you add a minimal example of the code, which fails to follow the redirect? and how this shall this be related to `google-apps-script` and `google-spreadsheet`? as the question had been formulated, there is no relation at all. also, it's a possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218726/square-retrofit-client-how-to-enable-disable-followredirects-how-to-intercept

Comment: do post your doPost code. Shouldn't the baseUrl be `script.google.com` and not `usercontent.com`?

Comment: I tried that. Still the same result :/

Answer (score 0):

Redirect could have happened because the server endpoint provided `https` and in your code you call `http`. Then the server would redirect to `https`. Only `GET` requests can be redirected, so others like `POST` will result in error.

Comment: you need to post your code. do you have: `OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                            .followRedirects(true)
                            .followSslRedirects(true)
                            .build();`